# How to access certain information in an API request - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "Saskatoon, SK, Canada" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Asquith, SK S0K 0J0, Canada" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "39.5 km",
                  "value" : 39512
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "33 mins",
                  "value" : 1950
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I can't figure out how to access certain information from apis. In this example above, I want pull out both distance and duration values and the status value. This is what I have currently:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

main_api = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"
units = "metric"
print("Example: Origin = Biggar, SK\nDestination = Saskatoon, SK")
origin = str(input("Please enter your origin: "))
destination = str(input("Please enter your destination: "))

url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({"units": units, "origins": origin, 
"destinations": destination})
print(url)

json_data = requests.get(url).json()
print(json_data[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must iterate the output arrays:

```
for row in json_data['rows']:
    for elem in row['elements']:
        print(elem['duration'])
        print(elem['distance'])
        print(elem['status'])
```